# How does waze change objects location with their localization?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, localization

The first image is when the language is set to Hebrew, the second is in English. Look at the word " Thanks: " in the image. How Waze managed to change the location of the word to a Right To Left language? With regular localization

**Thanks:x**

should have been

**תודות:X**

That's just one example. Waze does that a lot.

Waze supports iOS 4.3 and later so AutoLayout is out of the question. With regular localization I know you can change the content of the word but location? that's a first.

Can I set an `if` iphone language is English `then` change the layout to..? (if so that's a lot of ifs.."
Thanks

[image: Hebrew]
[image: English]

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, I do not know if there is any standarized way of doing that. 
But I see several options: 
1. Using localized .xib files or even full storyboards.
2. Changing that programmatically. Get the current localization and add some IFs to the view controller and re-arrange the items. If this is in a custom UITableViewCell subclass then overwrite the layoutSubViews (or so) and change the layout accoring to the locale settings. If you layout it within cellForRowAtIndexPath then apply the localization there.