# How to add rtl support to my ios app

Tags: ios, localization, right-to-left

I am localizing my app and wanted to add some rtl support as well (my app is currently in ltr).

What would be the best approach for providing such localization? I was thinking of creating different xib's for rtl and ltr, but then how would I load the correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked a question similar to yours not so long ago: [How does waze change objects location with their localization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14757764/1578927)

Your best bet would be to use a different xibs \ StoryBoard and differentiate between the two after checking the local settings. You could also ask the user for his native language to trigger the right StoryBoard (some users like to have controler of the language they are getting, even if there phone is in another language)
If you are going to support iOS 6 and there is a way achieving the above with `AutoLayout` but I'm not sure that's what you are looking for.